# My setText or my view is not working correctly.?

Tags: android, android-fragments

The assignment is in android studio. I need to make a BMI calculator. I also need to use a fragment and so far I have only had this one problem but when I click my calculator button my setText() is not displaying the answer. I am sure this is something simple but I am a newbie so any help would be appreciated.

```
    package jrodriguez.bmicalculator;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class BMIFragment extends Fragment{
    EditText weightT;
    EditText heightT;
    TextView out;
    Button btnBMI;


    public BMIFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bmi, container, false);

       weightT = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.weightEditText);
       heightT = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.heightEditText);
       out = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.veredictTextView);
       btnBMI=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.computeBMIButton);
       btnBMI.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               computeBMI(v);
           }
       });
       return v;
    }

    public void computeBMI(View v){
        double w = Double.valueOf(weightT.getText().toString());
        double h = Double.valueOf(heightT.getText().toString());
        out.setText(""+703*w/(h*h));
    }

 }
```

here is my fragment xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

      <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:orientation="vertical">

      <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/weightEditText"
        android:hint="@string/weight" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/heightEditText"
        android:hint="@string/height" />

    <Button
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="@string/computeBMIButton"
       android:id="@+id/computeBMIButton"
       android:enabled="true"
       android:clickable="true"
       android:contextClickable="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/veredictTextView"
        android:editable="true"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:elegantTextHeight="false"
        android:text=""/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: How does your XML look? Also does the code execution come inside compueBMI() method?

Comment: Maybe not do you think its my view? I am just starting to work with that so I didn't feel very confident with the view yet so I would not be surprised if it was that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution

```
public void computeBMI(View v){
    double w = Double.valueOf(weightT.getText().toString());
    double h = Double.valueOf(heightT.getText().toString());

    double bmiResult = 703 * (w / (h * h));
    out.setText(String.valueOf(bmiResult));
}
```

Comment: May I ask why do you think this would make a difference?

Comment: @Jennife, I have reproduce the code and it works in my device

Comment: Then its probably my view

Answer (score 1):

Remove the unnecessary tags from the `Button` and `Textview`. A button is always clickable and the `editable` attribute is not used with `Textview`. One of your tags is stopping the `listener` to function.